# How do I set default values for instance variables?

Tags: java, object, set

In my assignment, I'm given a `Food` class like this:

> ```
> class Food {
>     private String name; // name of food
>     private int calPerServing; // calories per serving
>     // must be >= 0
>     // min storage temperature // must be >= 0.
>     // max storage temperature // must be <= 100.
>     private float minTemp; private float maxTemp;
>     int getCalories() {
>         return calPerServing;
>     }
> }
> ```

And I'm having trouble with this part of the assignment:

> Write a constructor method for the `Food` class, to set the default `name` to `"Pie"`, the default `calPerServing` to `500`, the default `minTemp` to `25`, and the default `maxTemp` to `75`.

How do I set default values for `name`, `calPerServing`, etc.?

Comment: Just try some code and if you fail get ask experiences here.

Comment: Why is this Question closed? Seems quite focused to me. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*(I'm surprised to get to page three of search results without finding a simple version of this question to point to.)*

---

You have two choices for setting the default value of an instance variable (sometimes called an "instance field"):

1. Using an initializer on the declaration.
2. Using an assignment in a constructor.

Say I have a class `Example` and an instance variable `answer` whose default should be 42. I can either:

```
// Example of #1 (initializer)
class Example {
    private int answer = 42;
    // ...
}
```

or

```
// Example of #2 (assignment within constructor)
class Example {
    private int answer;

    Example() {
        this.answer = 42;
    }
}
```

Initializers (#1) are processed during construction just before any other logic in your constructor (but after calling the superclass constructor).

Which you use depends on the class and, to an extent, personal style. If the class is going to have multiple constructors but I want `answer` to default to 42 regardless of which constructor is used, using initialization makes sense because then I just put it in one place instead of putting it in every constructor. If the default for `answer` will vary depending on which constructor is used, or depending on a parameter the constructor(s) receives/receive, setting it in the constructor makes sense.

In your specific case, the assignment tells you to use a constructor.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest questions don't have answers. I've found myself in the same situation. Lol...

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting default values, you simply assign a value when you declare the variable like so:

```
private String name = "Pie";
private int calPerServing = 500;
```

and so it. If you want to overwrite those variables, you can. Alternatively, you can do it in the constructor like so:

```
class Food {
    private String name; // name of food
    private int calPerServing; // 

    public Food(){
       this.name = "Pie";
       this.calPerServing = 500; 
    }

}
```