# Setting final value in a constructor

Tags: java, implementation, final

I have the following problem. I have two classes - one is the base class and the pther is inheriting it. So in the parent class is an abstract class and it consists three fields - String name, String adress and int age. However in my task it says the value for age has to be set by default to be 25 years. My question is - How do implement this value with the help of inherited method setAge() in the constructor of the inherited class?
My abstract constructor looks like this:

```
public Student(String name, String adress, int age){
    this.setName(name);
    this.setAdress(adress);
    this.setAge(age);
}
```

and setter:

```
public void setAge(int age){
    this.age = age;
}
```

How do I do the implementation in the inherited class by using a default value?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43510129/3780625

Comment: Just pass the default value in a call from your child class constructor to the `super` (`Student`) constructor: `super(name, address, 25);`

Comment: @Maxouille No that is not quite a duplicate. This Questions adds the aspect of super class.

Comment: You should not use setter in the constructor. You can override that setter in a subclass to change its behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the superclass constructor takes three parameters in its constructor, and you have subclass with a constructor with only two parameters, you can call `super` to pass the two arguments plus a third default value to the constructor of the superclass.

```
public abstract class Person
{
    // Constructor
    public Person() ( String name, String address, int age ) 
    { …
```

And subclass.

```
public abstract class Student
{
    // Constructor
    public Person() ( String name, String address ) 
    { 
        super( name , address , 25 ) ;  // Default age of 25 for new `Student` objects.
        …
```

This is a silly example as defaulting a person’s age would not happen in real work. But the concepts demonstrated are sound.